# How do I resolve a raise NoReverseMatch(msg) django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch error in Django 3.1 on Mac OS Catalina?

Tags: python, django

I'm currently going through "Python Crash Course" by Eric Matthes. I'm on Chapter 19 trying to add a page to a web app where users can enter data. If working correctly, the user can write an entry about a topic that he/she is learning about. I wrote the code exactly how the book told me. Sadly I keep getting the following error:

File "/Users/jakeziegelbein/Desktop/crashCoursePython/learning_log/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'learning_logs/new_entry' not found. 'learning_logs/new_entry' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Here are the files of code:

**views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .models import Topic, Entry
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm

def index(request):
    """The home page for Learning Log."""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)

def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new topic."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topics')

    # Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)

def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Add a new entry for a particular topic."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic_id)

    # Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
    """Defines URL patterns for learning_logs."""

from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # Page that shows all topics.
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
    # Detail page for a single topic.
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
    # Page for adding a new topic
    path('new_topic/', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    # Page for adding a new entry
    path('new_entry/<int:topic_id>/', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
    
]
```

**topic.html**

```
    {% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Topic: {{ topic }}</p>

  <p>Entries:</p>
  <p>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}">Add new entry</a>
  </p>

  <ul>
  {% for entry in entries %}
    <li>
      <p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
      <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
      <p>
        <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_entry' entry.id %}">Edit entry</a>
      </p>
    </li>
  {% empty %}
    <li>There are no entries for this topic yet.</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

**topics.html**

```
    {% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Topics</p>

  <ul>
    {% for topic in topics %}
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
      </li>
    {% empty %}
      <li>No topics have been added yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}">Add a new topic</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

**newtopic.html**

```
    {% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Add a new topic:</p>
    
  <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">Add topic</button>
  </form>
    
{% endblock content %}
```

**base.html**

```
    <p>
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a> -
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a>
</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

**new_entry.html**

```
    {% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>
    
  <p>Add a new entry:</p>
  <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name='submit'>Add entry</button>
  </form>
    
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: It looks like you made a typo somewhere and wrote `'learning_logs/new_entry'` (with a slash), instead of `'learning_logs:new_entry'`

Comment: Willem Van Onsem, this was the mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main app's (learning_log project folder) `urls.py` do you have:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```